# Replacing commas in a string with brackets and commas if they don't exist

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to manipulate and clean up a string of database columns as follows.

Example Source string(s):

```
[foo],[bar],baz
[foo],bar,[baz]
[foo],[bar,[baz]
[foo],bar],[baz]
foo,bar,baz
```

(and so on)

Expected output:

```
[foo],[bar],[baz]
```

I have tried to run the following regex substitutions over the string:

```
        string columnString = "[foo],[bar],baz";

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(columnString, @"^\[.*"))
        {
            columnString = string.Concat("[", columnString);}
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(columnString, @"^.*\]$"))
        {
            columnString = string.Concat(columnString,"]");
        }
        while (!Regex.IsMatch(columnString, @"^.*\],.*$"))
        {
            columnString = Regex.Replace(columnString, @",", @"],");}
        while (!Regex.IsMatch(columnString, @"^.*,\[.*$"))
        {
            columnString = Regex.Replace(columnString, @"\],", @"],[");
        }
```

While this fixes up the leading and trailing brackets, it (obviously) doesn't deal with the commas where there is already an existing match in the string.

Can anyone suggest a method that would clean this up (it doesn't have to be regex).

Cheers

Comment: Why not just split on commas, check each item for brackets, then rejoin?

Comment: I suppose I really had it in my mind that I needed to use regex (even though I know there are other options).  Thanks for the simple solution (why do I over think this stuff ;) )

Comment: I posted a [fixed solution, please check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645230/3832970). +1 for a nice string related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a splitting and string rebuilding solution:

```
var result = string.Join(
    ",", 
    s.Split(',') // split with commas
        .Select(x => !x.StartsWith("[") && !x.EndsWith("]") ? $"[{x}]" : x ) // add [ ] to items not starting and ending with [ ]
);
```

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EDQUPh):

```
var strs = new List<string> { "[foo],[bar],baz", "[foo],bar,[baz]", "foo,bar,baz" };
foreach (var s in strs)
{
    var result = string.Join(",", s.Split(',').Select(x => !x.StartsWith("[") && !x.EndsWith("]") ? $"[{x}]" : x ));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Output:

```
[foo],[bar],[baz]
[foo],[bar],[baz]
[foo],[bar],[baz]
```

**Updated**

As there may be items with either `[` at the start or a `]` at the end you may use

```
var result = string.Join(
    ",", 
    s.Split(',')
        .Select(x => !x.StartsWith("[") || !x.EndsWith("]") ? 
            $"[{Regex.Replace(x, @"^\[|]$", "")}]" : x 
    )
);
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/4FYXJN). Result:

```
[foo],[bar],[baz],[test]
[foo],[bar],[baz],[test]
[foo],[bar],[baz]
```

Note that `Regex.Replace(x, @"^\[|]$", "")` removes a `[` at the start and `]` at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, this will deal with the split strings not having any brackets, which would typically be the way they are presented.  But if one of the strings has a bracket on one side, it ignores it.  The solution would need to consider all scenarios (which will become a bit unweildy)

Comment: @Ash Then add the test cases. You have no indication that this situation will occur

Comment: @Ash Updated the answer with a new solution.

Comment: @Ash You see, even if I am using a regex in Solution 2, since the string is first split the pattern is really very simple and only removes what it needs to remove: one and only one `[` at the start or one and only one `]` at the end of the field.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "[foo],[bar],baz";
str = "[" + str.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace(",", "],[") + "]";
```

Use `StringBuilder` if possible. I just gave you an idea using `String` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expression, here is the answer:

```
var input = "[foo],bar,[baz]";
var regex = new Regex("((\\[?)((foo)|(bar)|(baz))(\\]?))");
var result = regex.Replace(input, "[$3]");
```

Please see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Afnn3m

Comment: Thanks.  As a pure answer to the example given, yes, this seems fine.  Unfortunately, I think to get this to work in a real world example, wouldn't I need to split input and build a dynamic regex expression?

Comment: If you want to use dynamic regex expression, you can try:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/I4mIdA
`var regex = new Regex("((\\[?)([a-z]+)(\\]?))", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`